# Why is there a battery icon below my health bar?

Tags: hi-fi-rush

I noticed a battery icon appear under my health bar while playing a level. Why is there a battery on my HUD? What does it do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HiFiRush/comments/10szv5m/another_question_what_is_the_battery_that_is/), it refills your Reverb Gauge.
You can use the battery pressing down on the d-pad. It only lasts during the stage, one time use.